# flex-basis auto in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, flexbox

I am having a really hard time getting Chrome and IE11 to display a flex setup in the same way. For the footer to behave as intended in IE I need to use **flex-basis: auto** which in turn breaks the **justify-content: center** rule in the *.middle* class in Chrome. Firefox works as intended either way.

Why does the **flex-basis: auto** in Chrome behave differently from Firefox and IE as demonstrated in this pen: https://codepen.io/ninja59/pen/GzpOjO

In Chrome the desired result is achieved by removing **auto** in *.content* class but this results in footer being always at exactly 100vh as the page is rendered in IE. With long pages the content in the *.content* div then overlaps the footer when pages are overflowing.

So in summary:
**only** IE requires flex-basis: auto for footer to work as intended and
**only** in Chrome the auto setting breaks justify-content: center;

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: inherit;
  overflow: auto;
}

.content {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.contentwrapper {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.middle {
  height: inherit;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.inner {
  width: 320px;
  background-color: red;
  line-height: 100px;
}

footer {
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: gray;
  text-align: center;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">

    <div class="contentwrapper">
      <div class="middle">
        <div class="inner">
          box
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <footer>
      footer
    </footer>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `flex-basis: auto` in this case is the equivalent of `height: auto`, which is an invalid parent reference for percentage heights in Chrome. In other words, `.contentwrapper`, with `height: 100%`, needs a defined `height` on the parent (`.content`), and `auto` is not sufficient. See the duplicate for a more complete explanation. I also posted another duplicate that may help you achieve your layout more effectively.

Answer (score 0):

I think this codepen will help you.

[Example of the FlexBox](https://codepen.io/fernandopoli/pen/bzVLWW)

You have to change some class.

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

.container {  
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.contentwrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.middle {
  height: inherit;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.inner {
  width: 320px;
  background-color: red;
  line-height: 100px;
}

footer {
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: gray;
  text-align: center;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

[Also this very good to understand flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)